# NUnit won't load my unit test .dll file

Tags: nunit

[image]

I'm following the book Pro ASP.Net MVC2 and I can't move past this point.
What would cause this error?

Why does it say 'load an assembly from a network location' when my .dll is on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you are running it from your Desktop. Typically that path C:\Users\ (USERNAME) has special ACL requrements to execute from. Try moving it to the C: drive somewhere and trying again.

Comment: Did that really fix the issue because I have the same issue and my NUnit installation is already not in that "restricted" path.